How to calculate ISO8601 start time and end time
Since a month can have various amount of days, when a month is in the ISO8601 period, how to calculate start time or end time?
For example:
2024-02-15T12:34:56/P1M16D
There are 2 methods that I thought should be reasonable but generates vastly different result:



Step
Left to right (calculate most significant part first)
Right to left (calculate least significant part first)




0 (The original value)
2024-02-15T12:34:56
2024-02-15T12:34:56


1
2024-03-15T12:34:56 (+1M)
2024-03-02T12:34:56 (+16D)


2
2024-03-31T12:34:56 (+16D)
2024-04-02T12:34:56 (+1M)



How to handle the calculation?

Another slighly related question, assuming this:
2024-02-15T12:34:56/2024-04-02T12:34:56
Would the following be a valid expression?
2024-02-15T12:34:56/P2M-13D
This may reduce the confusion since the 2 methods I have above will result in the same end time.

To me personally it's not exactly clear what you are asking. When performing a calculation to determine a date in the future, you should use a library for that, because it is very complicated. Which programming language are you working with?
Also, what do you mean by "valid expression"?

"Since the real seconds for a month requires some context" - what does that mean? What are "real seconds", and why do they require any kind of context?

@ThomasHirsch I'm primarily using Python. The built-in datetime.timedelta is somewhat similar to the ISO8601 period but it does not support month or year. While there is an iso8601 package available, it does not have every ISO8601 features and can only parse date time string only.

Also, what I meant valid expression is can the number in period be a negative number? Like P2M-13D?

@NicoHaase Sorry I'm may have confused you. English is not my first language. I mean P1M requires some context to know how many days is in a month.
So like 2024-02-01T00:00:00/P1M, I would expect the P1M here meant 29 days since 2024 is a leap year, which makes the end time here being 2024-03-01T00:00:00.
But the P1M in 2024-03-01T00:00:00/P1M should be 31 days, as March have 31 days.

As usual: please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Your premise is sort of correct: There isn‘t any well-defined way of adding a period of months and days to a date. Each date library typically has its own way with its upsides and downsides. There will always be room for (unpleasant) surprises. Probably the best you can do is ask your users what they want and point out to them that no matter what they ask for, there will be some inconsistencies in the results.

I'll leave the parsing up to you, but it looks like you want dateutil.relativedelta:
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

s = '2024-01-30T12:34:56'
start = datetime.fromisoformat(s)
print(start)
end1 = start + relativedelta(months=1)
print(end1)
end2 = end1 + relativedelta(years=1)
print(end2)

Output:
2024-01-30 12:34:56
2024-02-29 12:34:56
2025-02-28 12:34:56


I just found out there is a package called pendulum that have better support for ISO8601 formats.
This works exactly as I wanted.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pendulum

interval: pendulum.Interval = pendulum.parse("2024-02-15T12:34:56/P1M16D")

start_date: datetime = interval.start  # 2024-02-15T12:34:56
end_date: datetime = interval.end  # 2024-03-31T12:34:56
time_delta: timedelta = interval.as_timedelta()  # 45 days = 29 (leap year) + 16

